# How to remove "/"/"" from data stored in firebase with App Inventor

Tags: firebase, app-inventor

When adding data with the block `call.StorageValue`, the string is saved in firebase with "/" before and after the string,

There does not seem to be any block to remove it, How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal firebase function that allows to separate the values and read them as such.

Example : 
on Firebase, *"\"English-EN\"*" is a single value sent from the app as *English-EN*

and *"[\"863674037411046\",\"863674037411046\",\"863674037411046\",\"863674037411046\"]"* is a list of numbers sent as *863674037411046*.

Try to retrieve the value with a button and to a simple label and you should see that it's displayed without the extra characters.

Source:check my app "harpokrates". I've made it as a firebase DB management demo and it uses nothing else. All values are stored as you describe and are retrieved just fine, without extra symbols or any need to trim the text.

ps:However if you do have extra symbols at some point, check your use of lists and lists of lists that might generate excessive "\" if you made a mistake somewhere. You can also use the "trim" or "split text" blocks but that would be bad practice. Finding the code error is best.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an escape character that escapes the special character `"` (quotation marks). This is common practice to use \ as an escape character to indicate that the next character has special meaning, in this case it is not the start or end of a string but actually part of it.

As such you can't actually remove it (just the escape character) and should consider how you got a quotation mark in the string to begin with.

You should however be able to remove the entire quotation mark `\"`